# Please allow a user to sort the experiences on the career site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, sorting

Just joined Stack Overflow careers and figured I'd chime in and ask for a feature. It appears that the order you insert the "Experience" items in is how they stay. I seem to have put mine in ascending order instead of the more traditional descending. It would be helpful if SO Careers had a sort feature for that section. I certainly want potential employers to see my latest experience first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completed and will be deployed sometime next week.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this.  I've similarly just entered all my experience in ascending order, but want it displayed in descending order.

Answer (score 4):

I think this feature would be great.  I would like to also see the "Education" section sortable.

Either some sort of drag and drop to arrange them the way the user wants, or an ascending/descending sort button.