# Ability to change order of education/experience

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, cv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please allow a user to sort the experiences on the career site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24927/please-allow-a-user-to-sort-the-experiences-on-the-career-site)

There are two possibilities for this:

1. The order should be intelligent based on data. I would suggest reverse chronological order, at least for experience; and/or
2. The ability to manually move the order around. Currently there's no way to do this if you want to maintain order and need to insert something in the middle.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24927/please-allow-a-user-to-sort-the-experiences-on-the-career-site